# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS refuses to install on a 64-bit Dell with 3 GHz Intel 64-bit Core 2 Quad CPU it says is "i386"

Tags: system-installation, 64-bit, intel, 18.04

System is a **Dell** with a **64-bit 3 GHz Intel Q9650 Core 2 Quad CPU**.

It **runs Windows 7 Professional (x64) SP1** and shows all 4 cores in Task Manager's Performance tab.  Most of the installed Windows programs are 64-bit versions.

**Ubuntu 18.04 LTS refuses to install, saying this is is an "i386" processor**.

It will not even allow the option to "Try Ubuntu"

This system supports multiple 5 TB drives as a NAS.  Also, 16 GB RAM.

64-bit hardware was introduced by Intel in order to support larger amounts of both.

It was never intended to cause people to get stopped as operating systems began to require more-specialized CPU architectures like AMD's "AMD64"

Who is driving this bus?  (pardon the pun)

**Why aren't all 64 bit processors supported by this 64-bit operating system?**

This doesn't make sense.

Comment: can you provide the exact model of the CPU in the question?

Comment: From Belarc Advisor:  "3.00 Gigahertz Intel Core 2 Quad Q9650"

Comment: [Intel Ark page](https://ark.intel.com/products/35428/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q9650-12M-Cache-3_00-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB) says it is 64bit, but i'm thinking that may be pre-64bit architecture standard...



check 'uname -a' and see if you have something like "x86_64" in that line. should be able to do that from the terminal in the ubuntu installer.

Comment: To be honest this looks like a kernel bug - suggest report it to launchpad - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+filebug

Comment: actually, confirmed....cpu doesnt support x86_64 [Intel Data Sheet](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/core2-qx9000-q9000-q8000-datasheet.pdf): 
**Supports Intel® 64 architecture**   (page 9, Intel® Core™2 Extreme Processor QX9000 Series and Intel® Core™2 Quad Processo
r Q9000, Q9000S, Q8000, Q8000S Series Features)

Comment: Q9650 is 64-bit acc. to this: https://ark.intel.com/products/35428/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q9650-12M-Cache-3_00-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB

Comment: intel-64 not same as x86_64 (aka AMD64)...intel-64 was intel's early attempt, before x86_64 ended up becoming the standard (around 2006ish? having a hard time finding a reference that's reliable)

Comment: Thank you for the edit, @SkanderBejaoui.  And in reading all these comments, plus the fact that in the Windows world it runs everything in 64-bit mode, I am still confused as to why Ubuntu calls it "i386" and refuses to load the installer.  (which also means I cannot do a `uname`).  Yes, I noticed that it does say it is for "AMD64" but never considered that really did mean that Intel was not included in the 64-bit category sometimes...  -->  I really would like an authoritative answer that I can accept on this subject.

Comment: No problem. One question, does the live CD boot at all? And did you try resetting your BIOS? it may be irrelevant but I've seen strange problems before caused by BIOS _mis_-configuration.

Comment: BIOS is fine, and the other Ubuntus boot OK.  I did have a problem with the Acronis True Image recovery disks - they had to send me a version that supports PAE, whatever that is.  18.04 is clearly trying to boot but simply stops at the i386 error message, so I can't even "Try" it.  It acts the same whether booting the DVD or loading the ISO in Virtualbox.

Comment: Should be 64 bit. x86-64 (also known as x64, x86_64, AMD64 and Intel 64) is the 64-bit version of the x86 instruction set. source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64

Comment: I can only conclude that when they say AMD64 they mean that you can only truly rely on AMD CPUs to run it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your **Intel Q9650 64-bit Core 2 Quad CPU** is [not supported by **Windows 10** either](https://communities.intel.com/thread/102696). It was released in 2008 and considered too old for modern operating systems.

Looking at your specs on [Intel's Website](https://ark.intel.com/products/35428/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q9650-12M-Cache-3_00-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB) I noticed it doesn't have hyper-threading. Also it doesn't have Turbo-Boost which is probably less of a concern.

More importantly there is the 64-bit instruction set which has evolved over time. Linux tests each CPU during boot to see if certain instructions are supported. I can't find the reference I was looking for but this [one](https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/Booting/linux-bootstrap-4.html) outlines the kernel checks:

---

After we have set up the stack, next step is CPU verification. As we are going to execute transition to the long mode, we need to check that the CPU supports long mode and SSE. We will do it by the call of the `verify_cpu` function:

```
call    verify_cpu
testl   %eax, %eax
jnz     no_longmode
```

This function defined in the `arch/x86/kernel/verify_cpu.S` assembly file and just contains a couple of calls to the cpuid instruction. This instruction is used for getting information about the processor. In our case, it checks **long mode** and **SSE** support and returns `0` on success or `1` on fail in the `eax` register.

If the value of the `eax` is not zero, we jump to the `no_longmode` label which just stops the CPU by the call of the `hlt` instruction while no hardware interrupt will not happen:

```
no_longmode:
1:
    hlt
    jmp     1b
```

If the value of the `eax` register is zero, everything is ok and we are able to continue.

---

To summarize there are many things your **decade-old** CPU doesn't support that modern 64-bit processors support.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, @WinEunuuchs2Unix.  This can serve as a reference Q&A.  I wonder if you might have a suggestion about the Title of the question - maybe some tweak that would help people searching via Google?  Perhaps mentioning that just because it is Intel and it is 64-bit, that not all are supported....?

Comment: By the way, the system makes a great NAS. It also has a large screen so is great for Amazon Prime Video and Netflix. It may be an older model, but with Windows 7 Pro it works just fine. And since it is 64 bit, it has no problem with 5 TB internal and external drives.   I can only conclude that the problem is that it is not AMD.

Comment: @SDsolar the problem has nothing to do with the CPU being from Intel and not AMD. **amd64** is the codename for all 64bit CPUs, and it is named that way because AMD was the first one to release a 64bit CPU

Comment: @SDsolar I think a title something like "Why aren't all 64-bit CPUs supported by 64-bit OS?" This would catch Apple, Windows and Linux searchers all in one big net I guess. You should ensure `this is is an "i386" processor` message is correct to the letter, capitalization and punctuation marks.

Comment: @SkanderBejaoui - if it were for "all 64bit CPUs" as you say, then my 64-bit Intel would work.  Clearly it is the AMD architecture, which is now being produced by Intel also.  The whole codename thing will be lost on normal people.  Besides, Linux has long been the way to use older equipment.  But now it is getting to be as demanding as Windows 10.  So on this particular computer I am sticking with good old Windows 7 Pro since it works fine and supports multiple 5 TB drives as my NAS, like any normal 64-bit architecture.  The whole 64-bit idea was to support hardware, not particular OSs.

Answer (score 0):

Please download 19.10 version (AMD64) and while installing,when you see a keyboard and a human icon on bottom center of your screen,press CTRL + ALT and run Install ubuntu with safe graphics.
It will work for Q9650 G41 motherboard,as i have the same specs.
I hope this will work for you.